# Cron python script import error

Tags: python, cron, python-import

I'm trying to execute a python script on boot. The script runs fine in a shell, but when I boot I got an import error for zmq package, here's the cronlog:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elachere/Documents/mg_app/r_server.py", line 7, in <module>
    import zmq
ImportError: No module named zmq
```

I saw many posts about this, so far I tried :

`-exports PYTHONPATH` in my **bash_profile** and run the python script via a bash script

-add these lines to my python script (before zmq import):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/elachere/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/')
```

`-set PYTHONPATH` at the top of my **crontab**

Unfortunately nothing worked, I still get the import error.
Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: unistall `zmq` and configure before installation(give true python package path). Or use `imp` module for calling any library.

Comment: I still got an import error using imp.